# Error in Emacs: ob-ipython-auto-configure-kernels: Wrong type argument: listp, 0.0

Tags: emacs, ipython, org-mode

In Emacs, when saving org-mode files, I constantly receive the message:
`ob-ipython-auto-configure-kernels: Wrong type argument: listp, 0.0`

The result of `toggle-debug-on-error` is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp 0.0)
  ob-ipython--get-kernels()
  ob-ipython-auto-configure-kernels()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(org-mode-hook)
  org-mode()
  bibtex-completion-candidates()
  #f(compiled-function (event) #<bytecode 0x158e23bbe639>)(((1 . 0) deleted "/home/alex/mybox/org/literatura.org"))
  file-notify--handle-event((1 . 0) (created) ".#stones.org" 0)
  file-notify--callback-inotify(((1 . 0) (create) ".#stones.org" 0))
  file-notify-handle-event((file-notify ((1 . 0) (create) ".#stones.org" 0) file-notify--callback-inotify))
  funcall-interactively(file-notify-handle-event (file-notify ((1 . 0) (create) ".#stones.org" 0) file-notify--callback-inotify))
  call-interactively(file-notify-handle-event nil [(file-notify ((1 . 0) (create) ".#stones.org" 0) file-notify--callback-inotify)])
  command-execute(file-notify-handle-event nil [(file-notify ((1 . 0) (create) ".#stones.org" 0) file-notify--callback-inotify)] t)
```

The problem occurred on a newly installed Ubuntu. On another computer with the same Emacs settings, this error does not appear.